# Hosting for Racket web app?

Tags: scheme, racket

Hi I wonder if I could have a free or paid hosting for Racket web app? Racket looks like fun to me but if the only way to run a web-app is to have my own server - that's too bad.

Is there something like Google App Engine for Racket? that would be superb!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I host my blog (written in racket) with ultrahosting. I wrote a [blog post](http://struys.ca/main/post/6/Setting-up-PLT-Racket-Hosting) about my experience with them. So far I've been really happy with it.

Answer (score 5):

You should really ask that on the [racket mailing list](http://racket-lang.org/community.html) -- there have been several posts about this in the past, with a histed vm slice being one obvious option, but there were other suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

To get you started have a look at [How can I Host a Scheme Web Server](http://www.lisperati.com/quick.html).

The short of it is you will probably need to pay to have a hosted virtual machine. The advantage to such a solution is that since the VM is your own, you should be able to move from one hosted provider to another relatively easily.

Comment: what is "schema"? why did you add this tag to the question?

Comment: I added the `scheme` tag to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Many shared web hosts allow you to build and run arbitrary programs on your account, so you can compile Racket/Guile/whatever, saving the binary in your home directory, and then have all of your Scheme files executed by the shell by putting something like `#!/home/username/bin/scheme` at the top.